# Replace the lowest value of an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of three ints and an array of three strings.

I want to be able to find the lowest int in the array and replace it if the "next value" is higher. If the lowest int is replaced I want to replace the corresponding string.

```
int [] counts = {matchA, matchB, matchC};
String [] names = {nameA, nameB, nameC};
```

For example say matchA is 6, matchB is 4, and matchC is 10 and nameA is bob, nameB is Fred, and nameC is jake.

The names correspond to the ints in their respective positions.

If for a new user there count is 15, I want to replace matchB, because it is the lowest and replace nameB because it is the corresponding name.

How would I code this?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: this is not very optimal as u can't sort the 'counts' array... try using an object that contains the name and count, then sort the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] counts = {6, 4, 10};
    String [] names = {"Alis", "Pop", "Fred"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    int newCount = 15;
    String newUser = "Jhon";
    int min = counts[0], position = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < counts.length; i++)
        if(counts[i] < min){
            min = counts[i];
            position = i;
        }
    if(min < newCount){
        counts[position] = newCount;
        names[position] = newUser;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would need to find the index of the lowest value and then apply to new values to each array at that index.

```
//This solution assumes counts and names are the same length.
int min = counts[0];
int index = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++){
   if(counts[i] < min){
      index = i;
      min = counts[i];
   }
}
counts[index] = newCount;
names[index] = newName;
```